# QGIS: intersect on a single shapefile

Tags: qgis, spatial-analyst, intersection

I am using QGIS version 2.14.1 (Essen). I'm trying to do some spatial analysis, including an intersect between the same shapefile.

Basically I have a shapefile with the geometries of all the events planned in an area at a specific time. I'm trying to find the intersect between each geometry but when I do an intersect between the same shapefile, it returns all the geometries. I guess if I save every single geometry as a different shapefile then it is possible but as I have over 1000 data values I don't really want to do this.

Anyway I can do this in QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the [Topology Checker Plugin](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html)  to identify all the polygons in your layer that overlap. Just add your polygon layer in the `Topology Rule Settings` window, in the rules add `must not overlap`. Validate to check the errors (effectively identifying all the overlapping polygons).

Alternatively you could add your data to PostGIS and use spatial queries to do this, something like [this](http://boundlessgeo.com/2014/10/postgis-training-creating-overlays/) perhaps.

Comment: Great thanks, that works! First time i use this plugin